# EnableRaisingEvents every 100 milliseconds?

Tags: c#, events, filesystemwatcher

I am just wondering is there anyway to turn on and off for EnableRaisingEvents every 100 milliseconds?
For example, initially, the EnableRaisingEvents is set true. when there is an event coming in, EnableRaisingEvents is set to false. 100 milliseconds after, EnableRaisingEvents is set true again. Until the file watcher receive another event, EnableRaisingEvents is set false again.
It is OK to miss events during the time that EnableRaisingEvents is turn off (set as false).
So I am just wondering how should I realize this logic in code. What confuses me is, the event is going to be fired anyway, should I use a tick to decide whether to accept this event or not?

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve.  Just keep in mind that setting EnableRaisingEvents back to false does *not* mean "stop raising events".  Events can get fired for some time after that.  And you'd better not forget to subscribe the Error event when you do this.

Comment: I think I mentioned "It is OK to miss events during the time that EnableRaisingEvents is turn off (set as false)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this (edited with Austin Salonen's suggestion):

```
private static Timer _myTimer = new Timer();
// ...
private static void OnTick(Object obj, EventArgs args)
{
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents ^= true;
}

// ...

_myTimer.Tick += OnTick;
_myTimer.Interval = 100;
_myTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Why not toggle EnableRaisingEvents in OnTick instead of the shared boolean?

Comment: @AustinSalonen I didn't understand what you meant. Could you clarify it a little bit?

Comment: Instead of `_raiseEvent`, use `fsw.EnableRaisingEvents ^= true;`

Comment: I think I'm missing something, what exactly is `fsw.EnableRaisingEvents`?

Comment: FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents

Comment: Ok, I just looked it up, I initially thought that EnableRaisingEvents was just a boolean. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Yes it works. Many thanks to all you guys. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Timer ( threading one) and set the elapsed interval as 100 ms for the timer , you may need to serialize the call if FS wather in created on UI thread,.